# Dynamic linked to libc in Linux does not have bind/connect

Tags: linux, go, bind, libc, ld-preload

Is that true that Go dynamic linked to libc in Linux and Mac is different? I am trying to evaluate the use of LD_PRELOAD (Linux) or DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES (macOS) to intercept the bind (listen) function. It's working on macOS but not on Linux.

On macOS:

```
❯ otool -tV main | grep bind
_x_cgo_bindm:
0000000100090134        bl      _syscall.bind
_syscall.bind:
0000000100090578        b       _syscall.bind
_syscall.libc_bind_trampoline.abi0:
```

On Linux:

```
# objdump -T ./main

./main:     file format elf64-x86-64

DYNAMIC SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000545a80 g    DF .text  0000000000000063  Base        crosscall2
0000000000545a40 g    DF .text  0000000000000037  Base        _cgo_panic
0000000000466ae0 g    DF .text  0000000000000019  Base        _cgo_topofstack
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.2.5) __errno_location
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.2.5) getaddrinfo
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.2.5) free
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.2.5) freeaddrinfo
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.2.5) gai_strerror
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.2.5) stderr
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.2.5) fwrite
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.2.5) vfprintf
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.2.5) fputc
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.2.5) abort
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.2.5) pthread_mutex_lock
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.3.2) pthread_cond_wait
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.2.5) pthread_mutex_unlock
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.3.2) pthread_cond_broadcast
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.34) pthread_create
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.2.5) nanosleep
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.34) pthread_detach
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.2.5) strerror
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.2.5) fprintf
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.2.5) malloc
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.2.5) pthread_attr_init
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.34) pthread_attr_getstacksize
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.2.5) pthread_attr_destroy
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.2.5) sigfillset
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.32) pthread_sigmask
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.2.5) mmap
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.2.5) munmap
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.2.5) setenv
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.2.5) unsetenv
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.2.5) sigemptyset
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.2.5) sigaddset
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.2.5) sigaction
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.2.5) sigismember
```

Is there anyway to force Go binary in Linux use bind/connect function as macOS?

Answer (score 0):

> On Linux:

The *binary* doesn't depend on the `bind` symbol, but that doesn't necessarily mean that you can't use `LD_PRELOAD` to interpose `bind` for that binary.

If that binary was built with `gccgo`, chances are it depends on `libgo.so.*`, which (on my system) *does* depend on `bind` and `connect`:

```
readelf -Ws /usr/lib64/libgo.so.22 | grep -E ' (bind|connect)'
    77: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND connect@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)
   224: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND bind@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)
140156: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND connect@GLIBC_2.2.5
163145: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND bind@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

**Update:**

> curious if your building with gccgo actually get hooked by LD_PRELOAD simple bind function?

Yes, it does. I compiled [this example](https://gist.github.com/abhishekkr/3beebbc1db54b3b54914#file-tcp_server-go) with `gccgo tcp_server.go`, and compiled this code:

```
void bind() { abort(); }
```

with `gcc -w -shared -fPIC -o bind.so bind.c`

Finally I ran: `LD_PRELOAD=./bind.so ./a.out` and it produced:

```
SIGABRT: abort
PC=0x7f83d3965884 m=0 sigcode=18446744073709551610

goroutine 1 [syscall]:
__pthread_kill_implementation
        :0
gsignal
        :0
__GI_abort
        :0
syscall.Bind
        :0
...
```

Note however, that my `ldd` output shows dependency on `libgo.so`, while yours *does not*. Here is what I see:

```
ldd a.out
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc574f8000)
        libgo.so.22 => /lib64/libgo.so.22 (0x00007f21d5f7d000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f21d5e9c000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f21d5e78000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f21d5c9a000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f21d7bb1000)
```

Comment: Hi, thank for your quick responding. I think my binary dep also have that. Still LD_PRELOAD does not get hooked

```
ldd main
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe545f4000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5609501000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f56096e7000)

```

```
readelf -Ws /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep -E '(connect|bind)'
   845: 000000000010a4a0    33 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT   16 bind@@GLIBC_2.2.5
  2556: 000000000010a4d0   155 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT   16 connect@@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

Comment: curious if your building with gccgo actually get hooked by LD_PRELOAD simple bind function? Or your binary actually have the `bind` symbol?

Comment: @user1929999 I've updated the answer. How _exactly_ are you building your binary?

Comment: Amazing. Thanks.
> On Linux: i used the standard `go build main.go`
> On macOS (cross compiled): `❯ CC=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc CGO_ENABLED=1 GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=linux go build -o main.linuxamd main.go`

Will look more into the gccgo.